# Loop until the request response message equals to "true" in php

Tags: php, loops, response

I'm trying to make a php script that would make a loop that would get the contents of my site/server and if the text response is for example "false" then it would do the same thing, basically will loop until the site's text response will echo "true". 
This is what i tried:

```
    $getcontents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/script.php"); // it will echo false
    if (strpos($getcontents , 'false')) {
            $getcontents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/script.php"); 
     else if (strpos($getcontents , 'false')) {
      $getcontents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/script.php"); 
}
else if (strpos($getcontents , 'true')) {
      echo "finished".;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way or even if it is possible and i apologize in advance if i did not explain myself very well. Thank you for attention!

Comment: You are missing a doublequote on your first line.

Comment: i just noticed that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular `while` loop.

```
$getcontents = 'false'; //set value to allow loop to start
while(strpos($getcontents , 'false') !== false) {
    $getcontents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/script.php");
}
echo "finished";
```

This will loop until `$getcontents` does not contain `false`.

---

You could also use a recursive function like this.

```
function check_for_false() {

    $getcontents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/script.php");

    if(strpos($getcontents , 'false') !== false) {
        check_for_false();
    } else if(strpos($getcontents , 'true') !== false) {
        echo "finished";
    } else {
        echo "response didn't contain \"true\" or \"false\"";
    }

}
```

This function should keep calling itself until `$getcontents` contains the word `true`, and does *not* contain `false`.

Comment: Don't forget that `strpos()` can return 0 (falsy).

Comment: yeah but i want that loop to be infinite until the response is true...

Comment: @Avery That is exactly what this does.

Comment: @Avery No problem. Let me know if it doesn't work as you expect.